# Use typescript to create object from array of objects

Tags: arrays, typescript, object

I have the following typescript code:

```
const a = [{ foo: 1 }, { bar: '2' }]
```

---

I wish to use `a` to create an object of the form:

```
const b = {
  foo: 1,
  bar: '2'
}
```

and the typing of `b` should be equivalent to the type:

```
type EquivalentType = {
  foo: number
  bar: string
}
```

Is this possible without casting? How can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure there is. This solution does not need `as const` like @Vija02's (although it is perfectly fine if it does).

Map over all possible keys in the array, then get only the type of that key using `Extract`:

```
type CreateFrom<T extends ReadonlyArray<unknown>> = { [K in keyof T[number]]-?: Extract<T[number], { [_ in K]: any }>[K] };
```

Then you'd just use this type in a supposed function:

```
function createFrom<T extends ReadonlyArray<unknown>>(list: T): CreateFrom<T> {
    // ... for you to implement!
}
```

Note that you might need to cast the return type. I don't think TypeScript will be too happy with this one.

And to finish it off, [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhjAvDA2gbxgMxCAXDARhgF8AaGDAIzgCd8ByAJnpIF0BuAKE6gE8AHAKYwAwjUFwoggGI0QAWwA8AFRiCAHlLAATCDABKE7eAA2vAII0acXooCuYANZgQAdzAA+D0gqoA0jAAlmAwjoK8IJgwyihgdvKUgjSsrAC0APz4AKKa1sBQKrHxicnkGCgA+kEhfqz4cGC8JB4otSRcnNqCwCa0wpgO+YHgMMDikjJySqoaWroGRqYWVjb2Ti7uXgAUJoHQ+MoAlPhiElKyCioeHaCQsJQ+Y2eTCltwh1wA9J8wvzAAeukgA) is a playground demonstrating the solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
// You might be able to simplify this
type TypeFromLiteral<T> = T extends string ? string : T extends number ? number : T extends boolean ? boolean : never;

// The "as const" part is important so that we can process the types
const a = [{ foo: 1 }, { bar: '2' }] as const;

// Get the final type
type ObjectUnion = typeof a[number];
type NewType = { [T in ObjectUnion as keyof T]: TypeFromLiteral<T[keyof T]> };

// By itself, this will get the correct value. However, we need to process the type separately and cast it to get what you want.
const b = Object.assign({}, ...a) as NewType;
```